# Build step (Execute shell) in Editable Email Notification in Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, environment-variables

I'm using Jenkins to configure a job which has a couple of commands in the "Execute shell" build step. I'm also using the "Editable Email Notification" plugin to send a post build email.

My build step - Execute shell has the following command:

```
#!/bin/bash
z='example'
a=$(curl http://www.'$z'.com)
echo $a
```

The above script is working fine. I would like to include my build step commands in the email body.

Here is the details of content section of Editable Email Notification:

`This is Your website data $a`

This displays as it is. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common use-case.
Step 1: Enter the commands in your Build Step (Execute Shell)

```
#!/bin/bash
z='example'
a=$(curl http://www.'$z'.com)
echo $a > /some/file/path/anyfilename.txt
```

Just put the variable output in a file.

Step 2: Next in your Editable Email Notification-Default Content:

`${FILE,path="/some/file/path/anyfilename.txt"}`